# Passing unused data to a python function: any loss of performance?

Tags: python, function

Suppose that I pass a 2D list (nested list) to a python function, which uses only part of that list, say, the first axis. Will python "transfer" or copy the whole array to the function? I don't want python to copy or transfer the whole data; it's inefficient for large arrays. Ideally I want a pointer passed only, or at most "transfer" the part that is needed.

```
def mysum(x):
    s = x[0][0]+x[1][0]
    return s

x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
s1 = mysym(x) 
s2 =mysum([x[i][0] for i in range(2)])
```

In this example, how are are x[0][1] and x[1][1] treated? Perhaps using generators could save memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No copy occurs; Python arguments are effectively passed by pointer, so the cost of passing a `list` is the same no matter the size or contents.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense!